# Is it possible to use a hash table with a range of values?

Tags: c#, wpf, hash, hashtable

**Situation:**

1. I have a set of X (e.g. 10,000) captured screen coordinates.
2. Displayed onscreen is a virtual keyboard. This is rendered as rows of adjacent rectangular controls (Border controls in this case).
3. I want to convert each screen coordinate into the key it would hit if I were performing standard hit testing, i.e. which key is the coordinate over.
4. This needs to be done as efficiently as possible.

**Possible solution:**

1. Generate a set of key positions that contains each key's screen coordinates (LeftX, RightX, TopY, BottomY) and update this if the onscreen keyboard is moved/resized.
2. Iterate through my captured screen coordinates and lookup which key it relates to.

**Question:**

Ignoring the potential gains of performing the loops in parallel, I want to understand the best structures and lookup techniques to use to take a screen coordinate and perform the lookup of the matching key based on the stored set of key positions.

Knowing that keys on a keyboard are horizontally and vertically adjacent, could I use this to optimise the lookup, e.g. create a hash table of rows of keys and use the screen coordinate's Y component to return either null (coordinate is not over the keyboard) or another hash table that represents the keys in that row. I could then use the screen coord's X component to do a similar lookup.

Bear in mind that keys do not often align into columns, so I would have to lookup a row, before I lookup the key in a row, as opposed to matching the screen coord's X component to a column and then looking up a key in that column.

I suspect that using standard WPF hit testing would be hugely inefficient as it tests against all possible visuals under the coordinate, when I only care about a single layer.

*Thank you for any help you can give me. It's possibly trivial, but I am not familiar with ways to hash based on a range of values*

Comment: I think approach is wrong. Represent every keyboard key as a rectangle, do `Rectangle.Contains(point)` for hit tests. The procedure will iterate an array of key's rectangles and do hit-test until hit-test is passed or end of array. You can optimize it a bit, by putting most *often used* keys rectangles into beginning of array.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? I'm probably missing something, but I can't think of ay purpose for this kind of verification, perhaps you don't need it! Or I *am* missing something, in that case more details will be helpful.

Comment: I have an onscreen keyboard and an externally captured set of screen coordinates. I want to turn the coordinates into a set of keys on which they intersect, so that I can use that info for further processing. I'm just trying to think of the best way to do it.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, but the point of creating a map is that I can optimise that lookup, rather than performing a linear search through the keys (including whatever overhead the Contains() method adds) for every coordinate. I am trying to remove that linear search as it's inefficient as I have knowledge of the layout that should allow me to optimise it. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest hit test is possible if you use indexes (as they works faster than anything else).

Assign to every key of keyboard an integer number (to example, scan-code). Then create a point map like this

```
int[] map = new int[ymax * xmax]; // 1920*1200 = 2.304.000 (sizeof(int) * 2.3 Mb)
```

While it uses quite a lot of memory, you can use it to map other things. It is also possible to index keys first (assuming there will be ~100 keys, you can use `byte` array instead to hold key indexes, but then you need an additional map from index to key).

Map tells who is the owner of pixel. It can be either 0 (no one) or someone (key scancode/key index/object index).

Hit test is as hard as

```
return map[x + y * xmax];
```

But in your situation, I'd recommend to represent key boundaries as `Rectangle`. While iterating over 100 keys (in worst key) and `Rectangle.Contains(point)` takes time, the solution might be good enough (and uses little of memory).